# Project IA in Python -- UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, search, graph

`

```
def iterativeDeepeningSearch(problem):
    def depthLimitedDFS(node, problem, depth):
        if depth==0:
            return
        if problem.isGoalState(node[-1]):
            return node
        for move, acao, c in problem.getSuccessors(node[-1]):
            if move not in node: 
                ode = depthLimitedDFS(node+[move],problem, depth-1)
        if x:
            return x

    for depth in itertools.count():
        node = depthLimitedDFS([problem.getStartState()], problem, depth)
        if node:
            return node`
```

I am trying to execute this code into the project(Pacman), but it returns an error: Un bound Local Error: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment....

Comment: You have a line `if x:` but never defined the variable `x`...

Comment: I forgot to turn the variable 'ode' in 'x'

Answer (score 1):

What **python** is saying to you is that you are trying to use `x` before any assignment on it. That is: you didn't use `x` **at all** and you are trying to inspect a possible value on it (which doesn't make sense).

What is `x` supposed to do in your code? Think about that and you will probably figure out what to do to solve your issue.

Comment: I forgot to turn the variable 'ode' in 'x'